# How to break long lines in Java

Tags: java, formatting, word-wrap, conventions

In the [official document of Oracle about coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html) they write:

> "Following are two examples of breaking an arithmetic expression. The first is preferred, since the break occurs outside the parenthesized expression, which is at a higher level."

```
longName1 = longName2 * (longName3 + longName4 - longName5)
 + 4 * longname6; // PREFER

longName1 = longName2 * (longName3 + longName4
 - longName5) + 4 * longname6; // AVOID
```

What do they mean by "higher level"? Is it related to the order of evaluation in the expression?

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't think OOO is the issue here.  Are you saying that the two expressions above are not logically equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

From a previous statement from the official documentation:

> "Prefer higher-level breaks to lower-level breaks"

In other words, avoid breaking nested expressions due to readability.

The more nested into parenthesis the expression is, the lower the level it is.

Comment: Makes sense. At this point, I was wondering if a line break immediately after  longName2 or after 4 would be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it would. Personally, I would also consider operator precedence. The expression inside parenthesis are going to be evaluated first. Then, multiplications, then sum. I would break into the sum, as the example. It's the highest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it sounds like they're referring to the order of operations here. Keeping operators of similar precedence grouped together on the same line increases visual readability.

Answer (score 1):

The issue whether we break the line inside or outside of the following term:

```
(longName3 + longName4 - longName5)
```

The documentation suggests that it is preferable to not break the above term wrapped in parentheses, but rather that the break should occur at a higher level.  It does not suggest *why* this preferable; both versions of the code you posted are logically identical.  One possibility is that breaking at the higher level leaves the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

No. The order of evaluation is the same but a "high level" means the order of evaluation, which in this case "outside the parenthesized expression".

This code has broken lines on the low level:

```
longName1 = longName2 * (longName3 + longName4
 - longName5) + 4 * longname6; // AVOID
```

This code has broken lines on the high level:

```
ongName1 = longName2 * (longName3 + longName4 - longName5)
 + 4 * longname6; // PREFER
```

One would prefer breaking lines on the high level to make it readable if you see the code evaluated at low level in one line.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? The **first** issue: _"The order of evaluation is the same but a "high level" means the order of evaluation, which in this case a parenthesized expression."_ - Aren't you contradicting yourself? The **second** issue: _"No. <...>"_ - Aren't this "No" contradict the rest of the phrase? I mean, the original poster asked _"is it related to the order of evaluation in the expression"_. And then you say "no". And then, after this "no", you repeat the same things the original poster said.

Comment: Yes. I meant that higher level of evaluation is a parenthesized expression, which contradicts to the statement of the document. The document state that high level of evaluation is outside the parenthesized expression. "No" means that in both statements the order of evaluation is the same regardless of formatting.@john

Answer (score 1):

"higher level" refers to a higher level of precedence.  At the very end of https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm there is a section on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean that the first string is better because of the layout and it is just more organized. I program in java sometimes and it can get messy so more organized strings are preferred even though others may work.